# Example of set of cardinality $\aleph_2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

I am looking for an example of a set of cardinality $\aleph_2$, such as the continuum is an example for cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: What is X1 and X2? It might be $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_2$, but $\mathfrak{c}=\aleph_1$ is the CH.

Comment: Aleph 2, of Cantor's infinite sets X0<X1<X2... X0 is the cardinality of natural numbers and X1 of real numbers.

Comment: You are using standard terminology incorrectly. The symbols do not mean what you think.

Answer (score 16):

If you think of "the continuum as an example for cardinality $\aleph_1$" then I'm guessing that you (or your professor) are (at least implicitly) assuming the so-called Generalized Continuum Hypothesis. Nothing wrong with that; the GCH is a perfectly cromulent foundation for mathematics, even if the set-theory experts around here are more interested in various exotic alternatives.

In that case, the set of all functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a good example for cardinality $\aleph_2$. **However**, it is important to realize that we are considering **arbitrary** functions. If you only count continuous functions, there are only $\aleph_1$ of those. So most of those $\aleph_2$ functions are very ragged, and their graphs do not look like anything you would call a "curve".

You can also get $\aleph_2$ as the number of functions $f:\mathbb R\to\{0,1\}$ which is the same as the number of subsets of $\mathbb R$, since a subset $X$ can be coded by a function $f$ such that $f(x)=1$ if $x\in X$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin X$.

Comment: Delightful cromulence.  If we didn't wish to assume CH, couldn't we just use the set of all functions $ f : \omega_1 \rightarrow \omega_1 $

Comment: @NickR The set of all functions $f:\omega_1\to\omega_1$ has cardinality $\aleph_1^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1}$. So, yes, instead of the full GCH we could just assume $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$. On the other hand, if the OP understands what $\omega_1$ is, then he probably knows about $\omega_2$ as well, so we might as well just use $\omega_2$ itself.

Comment: Oh, of course.  We would still have to assume $ 2^{\aleph_1} = \aleph_2 $.  Silly of me.  This is all still new territory for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nick: You haven't been silly before? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila If only!

Comment: @AsafKaragila In case your English slang is not great, when I say "If only", I mean "I wish".

Comment: @Nick: I watch so many TV shows and movies, that my slang cannot be not fine. And unless you're rejecting the law of excluded middle, it means that it's fine.

Comment: Could you please prove why the set of all continuous functions is still $\aleph_1$?

Comment: @HighGPA Since a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ is determined by its values on $\mathbb Q$ (the set of all rational numbers), the number of continuous functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is no greater than the number of functions from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R$ which is $$|\mathbb R^\mathbb Q|=|\mathbb R|^{|\mathbb Q|}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$$ which is equal to $\aleph_1$ since we're assuming the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @bof Thanks for your reply. I am sorry if my question is too beginner-ish. But could you please explain why a $\mathcal C^0$ function $f:R \to R$ is determined by its values on $Q$?

Comment: @HighGPA If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, then for any real number $x_0$ there is a sequence of rational numbers $r_n$ such that $x_0=\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n$ and therefore, by continuity, $f(x_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(r_n).$

Comment: @HighGPA If $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are continuous functions, then $h=f-g$ is a continuous function, and so $\{x:h(x)=0\}$ is a closed set. If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb Q,$ then $\{x:h(x)=0\}$ is a closed set containing $\mathbb Q,$ i.e., it's the whole real line, since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R.$

Comment: @bof I kind of understand this.. Could you please recommend any books or notes on the topic you explained to me\?

Answer (score 14):

The continuum isn't provably a set of cardinality $\aleph_1$ unless you assume the continuum hypothesis. The most canonical set of cardinality $\aleph_{\alpha}$ (for any ordinal number $\alpha$) is the ordinal $\omega_{\alpha}$.

...so for example
$$\omega_1 = \text{the set of countable ordinals}$$
has cardinality $\aleph_1$, and
$$\omega_2 = \text{the set of ordinals whose cardinality is} \le \aleph_1$$
has cardinality $\aleph_2$.

The continuum, i.e. the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$, which is not provably equal to $\aleph_{\alpha}$ for any fixed value of $\alpha$.

Comment: Though it is provably unequal to some values, like $\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: @Hayden: Sure, I could have put loads more information in about the continuum, but the OP seems confused enough! :P

Comment: That is true, just thought it might be worth mentioning. :)

Comment: Thanks! Any other "geometrical" example friendlier to visualize? I heard a professor refering to a curve with discontinuities in space (R^3) but didn't quit get it.. Any ideas?

Comment: @user192369: Not that there is anything wrong with Clive's answer; but there is nothing more annoying than spending time writing an answer to a question, asked merely 20 minutes ago, and upon finishing finding out that the first answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the generalized continuum hypothesis, $\aleph_2=2^{\aleph_1}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}=\cal |P(P(\Bbb N))|=|P(\Bbb R)|$.

If you think about the cardinality of the real numbers as $\aleph_1$, then you might as well think about the cardinality of $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ as $\aleph_2$.

Of course, as Clive pointed out, it is provably unprovable that $|\Bbb R|=\aleph_1$ from the standard axioms of set theory (namely $\sf ZFC$), so it is also unprovable that $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ has size $\aleph_2$. In fact under some set theoretic axioms we can prove that $\Bbb R$ is a set of size $\aleph_2$.

Instead, the definition of $\aleph_1$ is the least cardinality larger than $\aleph_0$. Namely, the least size of an uncountable set. The definition of $\aleph_2$ is the least uncountable cardinal larger than $\aleph_1$. Of course, the way I wrote the definitions here require us to assume the axiom of choice, but this can be slightly modified to avoid this issue.

Using this definitions, we have really standard ways to define $\aleph_1$. Consider the set of all well-orderings of $\Bbb N$, namely $X=\{R\subseteq\Bbb{N\times N}\mid (\Bbb N,R)\text{ is a well order}\}$. Now consider $\equiv$ defined on $X$ as the order-isomorphism relation. Then $\aleph_1$ is **defined** as the cardinality of $X/\equiv$, the set of equivalence classes of well-orders of $\Bbb N$.

Similarly, if we consider $A$ to be a set of size $\aleph_1$, then $\aleph_2$ is defined as the cardinality of the set $\{R\subseteq A\times A\mid (A,R)\text{ is a well order}\}/\equiv$, where $\equiv$ as before is the order-isomorphic relation.

Now if we consider an ordinal as a set $T$ such that $(T,\in)$ is a well ordered set, and whenever $x\in T$, then $x\subseteq T$ (for example $\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ are all ordinals). Then $\aleph_1$ is the size of the least ordinal which is not countable, and $\aleph_2$ is the size of the least ordinal which is not countable or has size $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Small typo : Line one should read $ \aleph_2 = |\mathcal P(\mathbb R)| $ , not $ | \mathcal P ( \mathcal P (\mathbb R )) $.  The second sentence states this correctly.  Or perhaps you meant to say $ \mathcal P ( \mathcal P ( \mathbb N ) ) $.

Comment: @Nick: It was an amalgamation of both, I suppose. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you vey much! Can you help me on where I can find the proof that R is a set of size Aleph2 ?

Comment: @user192369: Proof that $|\Bbb R|=\aleph_2$ depends on additional axioms. Much like there are axioms which when assumed can be used to prove that $|\Bbb R|=\aleph_1$. In either case, these proofs require quite extensive knowledge in set theory first.